# React Native: Semantic Issue: Unknown type name 'namespace'

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

## Original question:

Hello since I have upgraded mac os to `Big Sur 11.6`, I can not compile my React Native application.
I experencied many compile errors but I can not figure out this error:

`Semantic issue: my_app/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper/CertificateUtils.h:15:1: Unknown type name 'namespace'`

I tried:

- remove `node_modules`, `Pods`, `Podfile.lock` and reinstall
- `pod repo update` and reinstall all
- downgrade XCode to `12.5.1 (12E507)`

My environement is:

- XCode `12.5.1 (12E507)` and `13.0 (13A233)`
- Cocoapod version `1.11.2`
- Node version `v15.1.0`

My Podfile is:

```rb
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'RNCharts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-charts-wrapper'
  pod 'react-native-voice', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/voice'

  pod 'react-native-orientation-locker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker'

  pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '~>1.1.180'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_modular_headers!
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
end
```

And my package.json is:

```json
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.5",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.5",
    "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.x",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/react-i18next": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-elements": "^0.18.0",
    "@types/react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/react-native-orientation": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.5",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.7.1",
    "i18next": "^19.7.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "mixpanel-react-native": "^1.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "pusher-js": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.2",
    "react-native": "0.63.0",
    "react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-auto-scrolling": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.300.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.6.5",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "3.4.2",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.23",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-intl-phone-input": "^1.2.21",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-marquee": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "git://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker.git#master",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.x",
    "react-native-track-player": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.3.2",
    "react-native-zoom-lightbox": "^0.0.2",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.2",
    "string-similarity": "^4.0.2",
    "tipsi-stripe": "9.1.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@types/lodash.memoize": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
    "@types/react-native-calendars": "^1.20.8",
    "@types/react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/react-native-drawer": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "tsconfig.jest.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope someone know how to figure out this error.

## Solution (edit):

Following these steps solves the problem:

- Open project in XCode
- Select target and go to "Build settings" tab
- Search "Compile source"
- Change to "Objective C++"

[image: xcode]

Comment: Go to XCode and set Compile sources as to Objective C++ kicked out the error

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes @NullHypothesis I followed the above steps:
- open project in XCode
- select target and go to "Build settings" tab
- search "Compile source"
- change to "Objective C++"

Comment: Thanks @nathan-guigui - now when I do that, I get "Use of undeclared identifier 'FLT_MAX'" did you experience anything like that?

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to the missing import header `float.h` 
But I never experienced this issue, sorry @NullHypothesis